# Compiler -march flag benchmark?

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

does -march flag in compilers (for example: gcc) really matters?

would it be faster if i compile all my programs and kernel using -march=my_architecture instead of -march=i686

Comment: Well yes it matters. Otherwise that option wouldn't exist. It affects the instruction set and the scheduling that the compiler will generate.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does, though the differences are only sometimes relevant. They can be quite big however if your code can be vectorized to use SSE or other extended instruction sets which are available on one architecture but not on the other. And of course the difference between 32 and 64 bit can (but need not always) be noticeable (that's `-m64` if you consider it a type of `-march` parameter).

As anegdotic evidence, a few years back I run into a funny bug in `gcc` where a particular piece of code which was run on a Pentium 4 would be about 2 times *slower* when compiled with `-march=pentium4` than when compiled with `-march=pentium2`.

So: often there is no difference, and sometimes there is, sometimes it's the other way around than you expect. As always: measure before you decide to use any optimizations that go beyond the "safe" range (e.g. using your actual exact CPU model instead of a more generic one).

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that any code you compile with `march` will be faster/slower w.r.t. the other version. It really depends on the 'kind' of code and the actual result may be obtained only by measurement. e.g., if your code has lot of potential for vectorization then results might be different with and without 'march'. On the other hand, sometimes compiler do a poor job during vectorization and that might result in slower code when compiled for a specific architecture.